# Join a Recordset with a SQL table

Tags: sql-server, join, vb6, recordset

I'm working on a distributed database of sorts... I have to perform operations on a DB based on data that comes from another DB in the form of a Recordset. Often, I have to cycle through the Recordset and do something DB-side for each record.

In all instances, the Recordset that needs to be iterated (remote database) holds much less data than the data I will have to query (local database).

I have googled around for a while now, but since I found no useful information related to what I'm trying to do, I'm guessing that it's not recommended or not possible, but I wanted to make  a <strike>cry for help</strike> direct question before completely ditching the possiblity... so my question is:

Is it possible to perform a join between the data from a Recordset and a SQL table, directly on the DB, rather than on the client application? And if it is, how could it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand the question but if I understand correctly you are looking to join one table on the result of a separate query. This can be done by using the query in the table join as seen in the example below:

```
select 
    *
from 
    a
    join (
        select 
            SOME_COLS
            ,SOMETHING_TO_JOIN 
        from 
            SOMETABLES
        ) b 
        on a.SOMETHING_TO_JOIN = b.SOMETHING_TO_JOIN
```

Comment: Hm. Sort of... I need to join the result of a query with data that is already on a Recordset... Basically, I need to know if there is a way to transfer a Recordset to the database and convert it into a table, so it can be joined with other tables on the DB in the way you describe... I understand the question is a bit tricky; I'll try to word it better.

Comment: @ferc I hate to even suggest it because it is kind of hack but you could update your query to include the creation and population of a temp table or table variable.

Comment: @ferc Would it be possible to grab the data that is otherwise stored in the recordset in this query or is there a reason that is not feasible / desirable?

Comment: Sure. It would be possible, and not particularly undesirable (in fact, that's how I do all the processing right now), but I was looking for a more general solution, given how many different table structures there are in the different DBs. Actually, what you suggest crossed my mind, but yeah it feels ugly and error prone since I'd have to do all kinds of parsing to ensure the data can be inserted in the temp table... I guess I'm trying to break the mold here: SQL is not prepared to receive data and operate on it instead of simply outputting data and letting clients do the processing...